# What is the optimal way to assemble trees from query?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, tree

I have a table with a tree alike data organization (at the example below the `First`. `Second`, and `Third` are the nodes with subnodes - list of `Id` for the `Third` value):

```
+----+-------+--------+-------+
| Id | First | Second | Third |
+----+-------+--------+-------+
| 1  |   1   |   1    |   1   |
| 2  |   1   |   1    |   2   |
| 3  |   1   |   1    |   2   |
| 4  |   1   |   2    |   1   |
| 5  |   1   |   2    |   2   |
| 6  |   1   |   2    |   3   |
...
+----+-------+--------+-------+
```

The `Id`, `First`, `Second` and `Third` are the ids, that I need to transform into a tree, like:

```
[ 
    "1": [                   (First)
        "1": [               (Second)
            "1": [ 1 ],      (Third with list of `Id`
            "2": [ 2, 3 ]              
        ],
        "2": [
            "1": [ 4 ],
            "2": [ 5 ],
            "3": [ 6 ]
        ]  
    ]
]
```

What is the optimal approach for querying and assembling trees from that kind of data? I assume that a good option is to retrieve the groupped data from the db already, but I could not find any suitable example...

On the other hand it seems to be normal to retrieve the plain sql result and group the data into the tree afterwards.

Can anyone give a good example of that?

Comment: It is not clear to me which tree is represented here. What do First, Second and Third represent? How does that define a tree? What is the result you expect?

Comment: @trincot excuse me, I've updated the post with an example so it could be more obvious what do I expect to achieve..

Comment: Oh, so your tree has a fixed height of 4.

Comment: Yes, seems to be enough for me)